# Change button image dependant on boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have a button that is on my prototype cell in TableView, and what I'm trying to do is change the image of the button depending on a property of that cell being True or False. So, when the cell is being loaded, if this.value = True, set image as X, else set image as Y.

However, everytime the cell initially loads, its just showing the button as the default image from the IB. How can I get it to load with the right image?

```
bool paid = [cellArray[indexPath.row] paid];
if (paid == TRUE) {
    [row.btnPaidUnpaid setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kCommonRadioActiveImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if (paid == FALSE) {
    [row.btnPaidUnpaid setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kCommonRadioInActiveImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Show your cellForRow method code

Answer (score 0):

You can set different image for button's **default** and **selected** states.
You can achieve this from storyboard as well as programmatically.

Now based on your boolean value change button's state to default or selected - your image will change automatically.

```
myButton.selected = true/false

myButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "unselectedImage"), for: UIControlState.normal)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "selectedImage"), for: UIControlState.selected)
```